# Можно ли в YII2 не прописывать все группы в ACF, а брать разрешения из БД

Tags: yii2, yii, access-control

Можно ли в YII2 не прописывать все группы в Access Control Filter, а брать разрешения из БД. Как это можно реализовать?

P.S. Хочу избавиться от прописывания этой ерунды в каждом модуле\контроллере

```
' 'access' => [ 'class' => AccessControl::className(), 'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'], 'rules' => [ [ 'allow' => true, 'actions' => ['login', 'signup'], 'roles' => ['?'], ], ],'
```

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста вопрос. ACF - имеется в виду Access Control Filter или форматирование Advanced Custom Fields в зависимости от роли пользователя

Comment: Имелся ввиду Access Control Filter, хочу избавиться от прописывание этой ерунды в каждом модуле\контроллере 

        '    'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'actions' => ['login', 'signup'],
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                  
                ],'

Answer (score 1):

Да скорее всего вы хотите RBAC c ролями в базе

В конфиге указать компонент

```
'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
```

Применить миграцию, для создания структуры в БД

```
./yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations/
```

Пример

```
//Cоздание роли
$role = Yii::$app->authManager->createRole('admin');
$role->description = 'Админ';
Yii::$app->authManager->add($role);

//Создать пермишн
$permission = Yii::$app->authManager->createPermission('editUser');
$permission->description = 'Право редактировать пользователя';
Yii::$app->authManager->add($permission);

//Связать пермишн с ролью
$role = Yii::$app->authManager->getRole('admin');
$permission = Yii::$app->authManager->getPermission('editUser');
Yii::$app->authManager->addChild($role, $permission);

//Назначить роль 'admin' пользователю 123
$userRole = Yii::$app->authManager->getRole('admin');
Yii::$app->authManager->assign($userRole, 123);
```

**UPDATED:**

Или любой функционал на свой вкус

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => MyAccessControl::className(),
        ],
    ];
}

class MyAccessControl extends ActionFilter {

    public function beforeAction($action) {
        /**@var Controller $controller */
        $controller = $this->owner;
        $controllerName = $controller->id;
        $userID = Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? null : Yii::$app->user->id;

        /**
         * CREATE TABLE `access` (
         *   `controller_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
         *   `action_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
         *   `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
         *   UNIQUE INDEX `controller_name_action_name_user_id` (`controller_name`, `action_name`, `user_id`)
         * )
         */
        $result = AccessModel::findOne([
            'controller_name' => $controllerName,
            'action_name' => $action,
            'user' => $userID,
        ]);

        //Если нет, то кидаем Exception
        if (!$result) {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'You are not allowed to perform this action.'));
        }

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, это я все изучил, но если я назначу роли пользователям, у меня будет проверяться доступ автоматически ? То-есть у меня нет необходимости прописывать для каждого модуля массив access в behaviors ?

Comment: Всё зависит от разрешений. Обычно DBManager используется, для того чтоб роли можно было поменять не меняя кода, допустим из админки. Если у вас правила всегда одинаковые, то логично будет вынести их в какой-то абстрактный контроллер и потом наследовать от него все остальные, либо использовать Trait. Можете описать сво й AccessControl и AccessRule. Так или иначе если вы используете доступы, их нужно где-то хранить (в коде, в базе, итд)

Comment: обновил ответ, для своего AccessControl

Comment: Я на него ответил? Или что-то требует уточнения?

Comment: Мне как раз очень интересен вот этот вопрос - //Тут лезем в базу или еще куда-то и смотрим разрешен ли этот экшен для этого контроллера для этого пользователя. Достаточно ли будет проверки например checkAccessRecursive или нужно будет именно лезть в БД ? И было бы интересно есть ли уже готовые решения, в том числе по аминистрированию всего этого через GUI. Пробовал расширение yii2-user-management но оно очень толстое  и не понятное для меня, а расширение yii2-admin композер ставит уже 4й ЧАС, и я не понимаю почему так долго

Comment: **checkAccessRecursive** - это обёртка(которая полезет в базу) для `yii\rbac\DbManager`, который вы можете вообще ни использовать а написать свою проверку.

Comment: Композер не может ставить 4 часа. Может бряк сработал?

Comment: То есть в любом случае вместо массива access который ACF, я должен писать свою обертку для проверки, никакого стандартного решения для проверки из DbManager нет ? А что такое Бряк,я первый раз композер использую ? Видимо на моей стороне проблема т.к. все пакеты стали очень долго скачиваться.

Comment: Cтандартные решения - это не гибко и избыточно. Вы как программист сами решаете какой подход использовать, где и как хранить и обрабатывать правила. Если вам лень каждый раз прописать в контроллере права, тогда как я уже писал наследуйте от своего контроллера остальные, тогда указывать каждый раз не нужно будет

Comment: Понял, спасибо, я думал что уже есть оберка которая лезет в базу и проверяет права от туда, в зависимости от того какой экшн пришел, казалось бы логично имет ьтакой сниппет из коробки

Comment: Любую обертку нужно сконфигурировать, это же не искусственный интеллект, который сам поймёт что вам нужно, где вам нужно и при каких условиях вам это нужно

Comment: Ну, вот например установив модуль yii2-user-management в документации есть сниппет `public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        "ghost-access"=> [
           "class" => "webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\GhostAccessControl",
        ],
    ];
}
` он сразу проверяет права которыми наделен юзер и в зависимости от этого пускает или нет. То-есть не нужно ничего дополнительно прописывать, кроме как права в интерфейсе самой админки.